# How to find the determinant of a parallelogram using the vertices. (Using a matrix)

Tags: matrices, determinant

What it says on the tin. I already know how to find the determinant of a parallelogram using the vector components in a matrix, however, I am curious if there is a way to do it simply through the points given.

For example:
Vertex $A=(1,1), B=(4,1), C=(5,4), D=(2,4)$

Would there be any way I could put the points into a matrix and get the answer similar to how it is done with a triangle?

Comment: For others to better understand your question:$\\$
1) What's the definition of "determinant of a parallelogram"? Do you mean the oriented area?$\\$
2) You may want to quote the formula you do not want to use.

Comment: try joining the diagonal and adding the two areas of triangles( by the determinant method) else specify the method(about which you are talking about)